# find the next palindrome using loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, palindrome

i want to find next smallest palindrome but im not allowed to use some built-in function. so i create this code :

```js
function reverse(nums) {
  var reverse = "";
  for (var i = String(nums).length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reverse += String(nums)[i];
  }
  return reverse;
}

function Palindrome(num) {
  if (String(num).length < 2) {
    return num + 1
  }

  for (var i = num + 1; i < num + 3; i++) {
    if (String(i) === reverse(num)) {
      return i
    }
  }
}

console.log(Palindrome(23)) // 32
```

first function will reverse the string and the second will find the nearest palindrome.
on the test case, the result are supposed to be 33.

but when i run the code the result is :

> console.log(Palindrome(23))// 32

it only reversing the numbers.
could you help me to find what could be wrong from my code?

thanks before.

Comment: When I run your snippet it returns `undefined`. This sounds like a homework/interview problem, maybe you should start by explaining (or writing out) your algorithm for finding the next numerical palindrome (11, 22, 33, ...) and we can examine where it breaks down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct code is:

```js
function reverse(nums) {
  var reverse = "";
  for (var i = String(nums).length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reverse += String(nums)[i];
  }
  return reverse;
}

function Palindrome(num) {
  if (String(num).length < 2 && num < 9) {
    return num + 1
  }

  for (var i = num + 1; ; i++) {
    if (String(i) === reverse(i)) {
      return i
    }
  }
}

console.log(Palindrome(5));
console.log(Palindrome(8));
console.log(Palindrome(9));
console.log(Palindrome(23));
```

you were doing reverse of num in place of i

Comment: thank you for the answer.. problems were solved now !

Comment: The next palindrome after 9 is 11, not 10.

Comment: Thanks @RolandIllig for pointing out, I have fixed that issue.

Answer (score 0):

The check should be for reverse of `i`, not reverse of `num`. Try the following condition.

```
if (String(i) === reverse(i)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to reverse, as it would take O(n), if you iterate and check only for half the length of `num`, you can improve performance.

Here I'm matching the digits of number at places from beginning and the end.

So, the first digit should match the last, second should match the second last and so on. I any such match fails the number is not palindrome.

And this, way you only have to go upto half the length of number (after converting it to string);

```js
function Palindrome(num) {
  num = "" + num;
  for(var i = 0; i < num.length/2; i++)
  {
    if(num[i] != num[num.length - (i+1)]) 
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function nextPalindrome(num)
{
  while(!Palindrome(++num)){}
  return num;
}

console.log(nextPalindrome(22));
console.log(nextPalindrome(23));
console.log(nextPalindrome(232));
console.log(nextPalindrome(122));
console.log(nextPalindrome(1001));
```

Comment: OP is trying to find the next palindrome **AFTER** `num`, i.e. if  `num == 23` then function should find and return `33`.

Comment: @DrewReese ahh, overlooked that part completely. thanks, I updated it.

Answer (score -1):

I have used while loop here. You can try this:

```
function reverse(nums) {
  var reverse = "";
  for (var i = String(nums).length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reverse += String(nums)[i];
  }
  return reverse;
}

function Palindrome(num) {
  if (String(num).length < 2) {
    return num + 1;
  }
var i=num;
  while(i!=0) {
    if (String(i++) === reverse(num)) {
      return --i;

    }
    num=i;
  }
}

console.log(Palindrome(23));
```

Comment: The next palindrome after 9 is 11, not 10.